# Type of optional value in function

Tags: python, function, optimization, optional-parameters

guys. I am learning Python but I have question about "optional-parameters" in functions (I hope it's called that way, if not please correct me.).

So I have a function written like this:

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name, middle_name = None):
...
```

and I have question about last parameter "`middle_name`". When it is optional, **is it better to store it like string like this `""` or in form of `None`?** Are there some advantages to one or the other or it's the same? Does the one require the same amount of storage like the other? Or is there other better way to store the optional value?

Thank you for the answer. I am sorry for this "primitive" question but I wonder what is the best solution.

Comment: Semantically it's better to use `None` because it represents nothing while `""` is still a string with methods

Comment: Probably depends on the usage inside the function.  It's called a default argument

Comment: Many recommend using None as default to avoid [Gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) and to make functions more [easily extensible](https://unhashable.com/always-use-none-for-default-args-in-python/).

Comment: One could also argue that the middle name is a string, that may be empty, and having it as a string allows to concatenate it with other parts of the name, for example, without having to worry about its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest storing it as `None`. It's more readable. You can then write your conditionals as:

```
if middle_name is None:
```

or

```
if middle_name is not None:
```

Practically, some people have no middle names. None would be more appropriate for those people than "".